# How to send/pass a ArrayList from client side to server side

Tags: wcf, xamarin, arraylist, xamarin.forms

In my web service i have implemented a SaveSurveyAnswerAsync method in which i have a one of my paramter is arraylist. This is how i will read data(which is already been implemented) from which the call is made from xamarin froms app.

```
private DataTable ConvertArrayToDT(ArrayList Answer)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("int_SurveyQuestionID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("int_SurveyAnswerID", typeof(int));

            foreach (string item in Answer)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["int_SurveyQuestionID"] = item[0].ToString();
                dr["int_SurveyAnswerID"] = item[1].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

This is my save method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "Post",
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
 )]

string SaveSurveyAnswer(string ClientCode, int OrganizationID, string UserID, int SurveyID, int UserSurveyID, ArrayList Answer);
```

In xamarin froms it is asking me for ObservableCollection of object. Now when i am sending a list of observablecollection it return me an exception(and thats pretty basic why the exception is coming). so now the question is how do i send a arraylist when it is asking me for a list of observablecollection in xamarin

Here is the Problem screenshot [image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I that case I will advice you to use json file and `serialzes` it, like that you can save as string and when you want to use it, just `deserialize` it.

Example:

Serialize:

`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);`

Derialize to an object:

`var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl+context);`